# My Firebase ValueEventListener not being Trigered

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to Read a Food object from my firebase Reference and add it to a list of foods but nothing is being added to the list. Here is my code so far, any help on why no data is being appended to the list?

```
public class BrekoFragment extends Fragment{
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private FoodsAdapter adapter;
private List<Food> foodList;
private DatabaseReference mFoodReference;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.breakfast_fragment,null);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.break_fast_foods);
    foodList=new ArrayList<>();
    adapter=new FoodsAdapter(view.getContext(),foodList);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    mFoodReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("BreakFast").child("Coffee");
    final FloatingActionButton fab=MainActivity2.fab;
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)
        {
            if (dy > 0 ||dy<0 && fab.isShown())
            {
                fab.hide();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState)
        {
            if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
            {
                fab.show();
            }

            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }
    });
    prepareFoodData();
    return view;
}

private void prepareFoodData() {
    Food Rice=new Food("Rice","Rice is the seed of the grass species Oryza sativa or Oryza glaberrima. As a cereal grain, it is the most widely consumed staple food for a large part of the world's human population, especially in Asia",12,"http://2erape3gkyv5ojcr3ljlepou.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/cache/2015/10/veg-fried-rice/554794907.jpg");
    //foodList.add(Rice);This Works
    Food Tea=new Food("Coffee","Any of various tropical African shrubs or trees of the genus Coffea, especially C. arabica or C. canephora, widely cultivated in the tropics for their seeds that are dried, roasted, and ground to prepare a stimulating aromatic drink.",5,"http://www.ocean985.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/18/files/coffee2-637x416.jpg");
    //foodList.add(Tea);//This Works
    Log.e("FoodReference",mFoodReference+" ");

    mFoodReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Food food=dataSnapshot.getValue(Food.class);
            foodList.add(food);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("FoodList"," "+databaseError);
        }
    });
    Log.e("FoodList",foodList.toString());
}
}
```

If I add data directly to the list, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized it's an Issue with Poor internet here at home. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Since `ValueEventListener` is an asynchronous method, it may not get the result right away. So you need to declare your `List` in `onDataChange` method, with orther words, in the exact moment in which the data is changed. Than you'll have your `List` full of data.

```
mFoodReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    List<Food> foodList = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Food food=dataSnapshot.getValue(Food.class);
        foodList.add(food);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.e("FoodList"," "+databaseError);
    }
});
```

Hope it delps.